# Save json data in MySQL using php

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I want to save my following data into MySQL Database.

following code is showing me two warnings

1- Illegal string offset.

2- Only variables can be passed by reference in.

Please help.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=whois;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', '');
$items = array(
        'Domain Name:' => 'domain.name',
        'Domain ID:' => 'domain.handle',
        'Sponsoring Registrar:' => 'domain.sponsor',
        'Registrar ID:' => 'domain.sponsor',
        'Domain Status:' => 'domain.status.',
        'Status:' => 'domain.status.',
        'Name Server:' => 'domain.nserver.',
        'Nameservers:' => 'domain.nserver.',
        'Maintainer:' => 'domain.referer',
);

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO temdata VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

foreach ($items as $row) {

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $row['domainname']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $row['domainid']);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $row['registrar']);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $row['registrarid']);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $row['domainstatus']);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $row['status']);
    $stmt->bindParam(7, $row['server']);
    $stmt->bindParam(8, $row['nameservers']);
    $stmt->bindParam(9, $row['maintainer']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Let's start with this one. `$row` is not an array, it's a value. So `$row['domainname']`, `$row['domainid']`, ... are all wrong.

Comment: If you used named parameter, after bothering to load an array of data, this might well be a lot easier

Comment: now its showing me Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param()

Comment: Lets start at the beginning. Are you using PDO or MYSQLI_ datbase extension

Comment: $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=whois;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', '');

Comment: That's because you're mixing `mysqli` and `PDO` methods. Pick one API and be consistent with that.

Comment: I really dont know what to use. could you please help me here?

Comment: Are you trying to insert data from another table? If so, skip the bindings. You're not passing through potentially bad data. You're just moving around what's already there.

Comment: Explain the array you show us. And the column names in your database would also be useful information

Comment: RTM, [http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and fix the issue I pointed in the [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165652/save-json-data-in-mysql-using-php#comment71496337_42165652) above.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul You can still use `?,?,?` style parameters in PDO

Comment: No I'm not inserting data from another table. just want to save that json data into database

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, he can. I'm just pointing out that `bind_param()` and `bindParam()` are two different methods, which belong to two different APIs. [I believe OP is little bit confused here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165652/save-json-data-in-mysql-using-php#comment71496526_42165652).

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Oh right, I only see `bindParam()` sorry I must have missed something

Comment: column names are the same I'm using with $row['column_name'].

Comment: I don't see any json. I see an array that looks like named parameters as a key. Your foreach is iterating through a single-dimensional array, so you're not getting what you think you are, and the keys you're trying to get are not even in the array you listed. If this is pseudocode, show your actual code. If it's not pseudocode, re-evaluate what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Sorry my bad. not json data. I want to save array data into databese

Comment: Did you manually create that array or is something else providing the data in that format?

Comment: I'm getting that data from web in string format. I'm able to display the data on my webpage. but I'm not able to save it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work, but I personally would want something more robust before I released it.

```
$items = array(
        'Domain Name:' => 'domain.name',
        'Domain ID:' => 'domain.handle',
        'Sponsoring Registrar:' => 'domain.sponsor',
        'Registrar ID:' => 'domain.sponsor',
        'Domain Status:' => 'domain.status.',
        'Status:' => 'domain.status.',
        'Name Server:' => 'domain.nserver.',
        'Nameservers:' => 'domain.nserver.',
        'Maintainer:' => 'domain.referer',
);

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO temdata VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$col=1;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $stmt->bindParam($col, $item);
    $col++;
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you soo much. you are a lifesaver :)

Comment: @Siddhesh Please *accept* the answer to close the question, otherwise it'd be floating around as *open* question. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove trailing dot (.) from array values

```
$items = array(
    'Domain Name:' => 'domain.name',
    'Domain ID:' => 'domain.handle',
    'Sponsoring Registrar:' => 'domain.sponsor',
    'Registrar ID:' => 'domain.sponsor',
    'Domain Status:' => 'domain.status',
    'Status:' => 'domain.status',
    'Name Server:' => 'domain.nserver',
    'Nameservers:' => 'domain.nserver',
    'Maintainer:' => 'domain.referer',
);
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO temdata VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$i = 1;
foreach ($items as $row) {
    $stmt->bindParam($i, $row);
    $i++;
}

$stmt->execute();
`
```